# Display image from database Nvarchar type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

hi i'm using nvarchar and tryied too ref till the map too display the image like ~/image/pics.jpg. in my tabel i got 3 column id,image and text. id=int, image=nvarchar(max) text= nvarchar(50).

How can I display them? Does anyone know of a guide or tutorial I can follow?

i have search every where but they using binary and image typ. i can only display text and ID if i want but on image it shows the icon that ther should be an image but it didn't display?

controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var pics = db.image.ToList();

    return View(pics);
    }
```

view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
<tr>
<img src='@item.image' />
<tr/>
<tr>
@item.text
<tr/>
```

Comment: **WHY** is an image stored as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` ???? That doesn't make any sense at all! That's a **textual** column - it's definitely **NOT** suitable for a **binary** thing like an image! You need to use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead......

Comment: ok i don't know how 2 use varbinary i don't know how to link it in database. i mean the url there the image is. u have any guide?

Comment: You gave way too little details in your question.  We need to see input and outputs.  The more detail you give the better we can help you.  Would you be able to answer this question by the amount of detail that you have given?

Comment: I'm keen to help you get this sortedd out but I am going ask that you provide me with some more details. Show me some sample data that is in the image column and let me know your directory structure where the images reside. This should help me then I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a helper method that I use in my view:

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url)
{
     return Image(htmlHelper, url, null);
}

public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url, object htmlAttributes)
{
     TagBuilder imgTag = new TagBuilder("img");
     UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

     imgTag.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content(url));
     imgTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

     return new HtmlString(imgTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

In my view I have the following:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@foreach (var file in Model.UploadedFiles)
{
     @Html.Image(file.Path)<br />
}
```

My view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public IList<UploadedFile> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

UploadedFile class:

```
public class UploadedFile
{
     public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Now how you populate the UploadedFiles property is up to you.  I would have done it something like this with a database call:

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
     {
          // Database call to return paths
          UploadedFiles = fileService.GetFiles()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but this will help you in a direction.  Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i can't make the image to display. i just want 2 display the image. i know i'm realy anoying but i'm new in this. :( u know if ther any giude or torturial 4 this?